# Is there a possibility to differentiate wether the user pressed the home button or locked the phone in unity3d for android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-homebutton

I would like to know if it's possible to detect wether the OnApplicationPause/Focus function was called because the android user locked his phone or if the user pressed one of the three buttons so the app gets minimized.
I'm using Unity3d.
Thank you